# Rails - how to save options chosen by user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: Meal and Tag. They are associated by HABTM. What I want to do is to add new meal. So I have new.html where is name field, preparation field, and all tags (represented by toggle-buttons - every tag has own toggle-button). User can clicked tags, which want to save in this meal.
And here is a problem. I can display all tags, but I have no idea how can I tell rails to save only clicked tags. 
Could you help me find right approach?

oh, and there is a user too (user has many meals), but I thing it doesn't matter.
Here is my view:

```
<%= form_for(@meal,:html => {:class => "meal-data-form"}) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object%>

<%= f.label :name, "Nazwa *" %>
<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'%>

<%= f.label :preparation, "Sposób przyrządzenia" %>
<%= f.text_area :preparation, class: 'form-control' %>

<h3>Określ tagi dla tego posiłku</h3>
<div id="tags-associated-with-meal">
    <h4>Rodzaj posiłku</h4>
    <div id="associated-nutrient-tags">
        <% current_user.nutrient_tags.each do |nutrient_tag| %>
            <button id="associated-type-tag-<%= nutrient_tag.id %>" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
                <%= nutrient_tag.name %>
            </button>
        <% end %>
    </div>
 </div>

<%= f.submit yield(:button_name), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use a toggle button to do this, I would probably use checkboxes.

This is what you would do if you used checkboxes:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :nutrient_tags_ids,  current_user.nutrient_tags, :id, :name do |b| %>
  <div class="collection-check-box">
    <%= b.check_box %>
    <%= b.label %>
  </div>
```

Here is something for reference: http://www.sitepoint.com/save-multiple-checkbox-values-database-rails/

And here is the Rails `collection_check_boxes` official documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I saw similar approach for checkboxes, but I really want to use toggle-buttons. They should look like tags. Is any option to check toggle status by params[:toggle-name] in controller?

Comment: I would try this then: http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ it's bootstrap checkboxes styled as toggles.

Comment: It looks good. But I have a problem with this gem. I followed instruction: add to Gemfile, install, add requires (ccs, js), and it doesn't work. Have you got any idea, why? Or maybe is other way to install it?

Comment: Ok I fixed it by adding lines from your link to the head section. I don't know why I didn't it before. By still I have a problem. Because these toggle-butons are like a switch option. Styling is unsuitable for my needs. Is it any option to change these toggle-button on common button with two states (different color for example)?